# creating new object throws copywithzone unrecognized selector error in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsobject

I have a simple object that looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@class MyUser;

@interface MyCycle : NSObject


@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *myNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyUser *user;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *data;


@end
```

Here is the implementation:

```
#import "MyCycle.h"

@implementation MyCycle



@end
```

Here is the user object:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>


@interface MyUser : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *usersName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *gender;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *password;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *phoneNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *profileImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFFile *profileImageFile;




@end
```

I allocate this object and populate it with the following:

```
MyCycle *cycle = [[MyCycle alloc] init];
        cycle.myNumber = @1;
        cycle.data = [[NSArray alloc]init];
```

I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyCycle copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's happening because you haven't shown us all the code.

Comment: Do you have a custom init method for `MyCycle`? Could you please post it?

Comment: You still have not shown us the code where the failure is occurring.  You need to learn how to use the debugger to find the point of failure.

Comment: Post the code that is actually causing the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, you have a code that attempts to copy an `MyCycle` instance. Perhaps you use an object as a key to a dictionary? If you wish to continue with this behavior, you need to implement the [NSCopying protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCopying) for your class.

Comment: so for object properties I should use strong as opposed to copy ?  I changed every place I use copy to strong and it works.

Comment: @Atma No no, if you want to copy that's fine. Just need to implement the actual copy.

Comment: @Atma There is nothing wrong with any of the code you posted. No need to change any of the `copy` properties to `retain`. Update your question with the actual code causing the crash.

Comment: NSDictionary copies objects used as keys by default, right? In that case, omplementing copying seems to be the only solution.

Comment: @NicolasMiari But so far we have no idea what code is causing the problem and whether a dictionary is being used with the `MyCycle` objects as keys.

Comment: Actually @rmaddy is correct. Once the code is shown, I will add to my answer.

Comment: It's psychology. The subconscious mind doesn't want others to see your mistake. The error is in the bit of code that you are completely convinced can't be the problem and that you refuse to post.

Answer (score 0):

one of a reason, that this error could happen is The name of the variable you declare or your custom class is already used by the iOS SDK. You can say it’s a keyword. And the variable name can never be a keyword because it confuses your XCode (Objective C Compiler).

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered for a while but for posterity here is an additional one that may be the why. Check your bindings. This also will happen if you accidentally bind the controller in Interface Builder and the UI control tries to use the actual controller as a string or other value type which causes the `copyWithZone:` to be issued.

For instance if File's Owner has a nested controller and you accidentally bind to `innerController` instead of `innerController.property`.

Answer (score 0):

It's old question but probably you haven't @synthesized properties 'data', 'myNumber'. In other words you have no setter for those properties.